# Can't connect to mongo server after restarting the EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongodb

guys I'm new to AWS and what I did was I restarted the Ec2 Instance of mongo via a Schedule. But after restarting I am unable to connect to the mongo server from anywhere. *i.e* Robomongo (local machine) also the instance that uses the mongo service for example `mongo-qa` instance is used by `app-qa` which isn't working because mongo is unreachable (I think.). The instance is up and running tho.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need a bit more information to help you out.

Things to look at:

- is your MongoDB instance on public or private subnet? 
  Check if it has a public IP associated to it
- how are the security groups configured? 
  If the instance is reachable through public IP, you should have on the security groups the public IP of your local machine
- are you able to ssh into it? 
  Maybe the mongodb service was not configured to be started along with the ec2 startup process

Comment: Hi thanks, The problem was the mongodb service was not started automatically.
I connected to the instance following the link below and restarted the service `sudo service mongod restart` https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstarts/latest/vmlaunch/step-2-connect-to-instance.html